# Twig on Wordpress - Get author post name

Tags: php, wordpress, post, twig, author

I'm using a wp template based on Twig files called Realia. I'm using to buddypress and I want to add a link button to the author profile of post. 
I found [this page](https://github.com/jarednova/timber/wiki/TimberPost#author) who help me a lot but I want to find the author name and what I found is the ID author. Someone can help me ?

Here's my code :

```
 <a href="/members/{{post.post_author}}">Envoyer un message au propriétaire</a>
```

Comment: Have you already tried to generate the href link as `{{post.author.link}}`?

Comment: Yes I did but it do nothing.. It just redirect to the members page
I tried too post.post_author_name, post_authorname, post.post.author.name...
But nothing work I just get the ID and not the name..

Comment: What about {{post.author.name}}?

Comment: It doesn't work too :/

On wordpress the php is `<?php the_author(); ?> `. There's no way to include that in twig ? I am a newbie on Twig template :/

Comment: So the user property don't work as expected? Have you tried {{post.author.first_name}} also?

Comment: Yes I did
When I try something else than what I posted it do nothing except redirect to /members/ like I wrote but what is on {{...}} doesn't work

Comment: Do you have an other idea ? I just want a link which redirect to a members profile which URL is " /members/ " + member name..
The only thing that I get is the member ID and not the name..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way ! Thank a lot for your replies ! :)

```
    {% set id = post.post_author %}
    {% set author = wp.bp_core_get_username(id) %}
    <FORM ACTION="/members/{{author}}">
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Envoyer un message au propriétaire"></FORM>
```